# How to link a huge Res if RLink32 fails

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource, delphi-2007, resource-files

In a project, during the compilation, the resource-linking process fails with this error: **[DCC Error] E2161 Error: RLINK32: Out of memory!**.

The project includes a huge res file (about 400 Mb). The error is not triggered if the res file size doesn't exceed 250 Mb. 
At it's only some RCDATA, I could keep the data in an external file but I would like to know if there is a workaround for this issue.

Comment: Note that the error appends whatever the resource compiler used to generate the huge res file (brcc32 or micorosft rc)

Comment: Actually I take that back. Linking a 400MB resource into your executable is simply a bad idea. It will consume a very large chunk of address space and probably result in DLL relocations and thus slower load times, worse system memory use etc. The right solution here is a separate file.

Comment: Yes but the program is actually an installer, so in this particular case it IS a good idea. I just test its limits...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an external resource linker in a post-build event (Project->Options->Build Events). Below is an example usage for '[ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/)' (which is able to do pretty much anything with the command line that its GUI can do).

```
"C:\...\ResHacker.exe" -addskip "$(OUTPUTPATH)", "$(OUTPUTPATH)", "C:\...\icons.res",,,
```

The example adds the resources in icons.res which are not already in the executable and overwrites the executable. I have no idea if it chokes with your big resource, but you can try using other alternatives if it does.

Comment: Ok, I see, I would have to compile with a "fake" RCDATA and would replace them with the true, manually or  with a post event, after the build. I think that's also what has suggested D.H in his comment. So far it looks like the only way to overcome the problem.

Comment: @az01 - I don't think you need a fake resource.

Answer (score 0):

look on the application if there are components that contain large elements like bitbtn with glyph image bmp, abusing it consumes memory. Good Luck.